# Using geometry reader to Center the Rectangle

Tags: swiftui, geometryreader

I'm trying to use GeometryReader to make a Card View (to use in a card game).
This Card is going to have 3 Shapes on it.
I'm trying to center these 3 Shapes using GeometryReader (starting with the first shape, Rectangle), but it doesn't work.
What am I doing wrong?

Here's how I WANT it to look like: [Here's how I want it to look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sl8WS.png)

Here's how it ACTUALLY looks like: [Here's how it actually looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AtmuT.png)

```
struct Card: View {
var body: some View {
    ZStack {
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).stroke(lineWidth: 3)
        VStack {
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Rectangle()
                .size(
                    width: geometry.size.width * 0.75,
                    height: geometry.size.height * 0.75
                )
                .position(
                    x: geometry.size.width / 2,
                    y: geometry.size.height / 2
                )
            }
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Circle()
                .size(
                    width: geometry.size.width * 0.75,
                    height: geometry.size.height * 0.75
                )
                .position(
                    x: geometry.size.width / 2,
                    y: geometry.size.height / 2
                )
            }
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                Rectangle()
                .size(
                    width: geometry.size.width * 0.75,
                    height: geometry.size.height * 0.75
                )
                .position(
                    x: geometry.size.width / 2,
                    y: geometry.size.height / 2
                )
            }
        }

    }
    .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
}
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible variant of layout. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14

[image]

```
struct Card3: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0).stroke(lineWidth: 3)
            GeometryReader { geometry in
                VStack {
                    Color.clear.overlay(Rectangle()
                        .frame(
                            width: geometry.size.width * 0.75,
                            height: geometry.size.height / 3 * 0.75
                        ))
                    Color.clear.overlay(Circle()
                        .frame(
                            width: geometry.size.width * 0.75,
                            height: geometry.size.height / 3 * 0.75
                        ))
                    Color.clear.overlay(Rectangle()
                        .frame(
                            width: geometry.size.width * 0.75,
                            height: geometry.size.height / 3 * 0.75
                        ))
                }.frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
            }
        }
        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. I'm still curious though, why  my code using .position() didn't work.
According to the documentation, .position() should center the View on x y.
So what did I do wrong.  Could you help me solve it using this .position()?

From documentation: Summary
Fixes the center of the view at the specified coordinates in its parent’s coordinate space.
Parameters x The x-coordinate at which to place the center of this view.
y The y-coordinate at which to place the center of this view.
Returns A view that fixes the center of this view at x and y.

Comment: *According to the documentation, .position() should POSITION THE center OF the View on x y